# ArcPy TableToNumPyArray TypeError

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, table, numpy

I have a geodatabase table that I want to convert to a numpy array to create a Pandas dataframe. Using the arcpy [TableToNumPyArray](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/tabletonumpyarray.htm) function on the table object fails.

```py
import arcpy, numpy

# `tbls` is a list of gdb tables to convert
np_array = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(tbls[-2], ("Name", "MinPS", "MaxPS", "ZOrder"))
np_array
```

Returns -

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-f3eded008503> in <module>
----> 1 np_array = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(tbls[-2], ("Name", "MinPS", "MaxPS", "ZOrder"))
      2 np_array

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I can successfully validate the table path (`tbls[-2]`) as a string, use `arcpy.GetCount_management(tbls[-2])`, and use `arcpy.ListFields(tbls[-2])`. I also tried using a different combination of fields.

Comment: Specify how to treat Nulls in input table.

Comment: What @FelixIP suggests can be implemented with the `skip_nulls` or `null_value` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felix and user2856 are both correct about nulls with TableToNumPyArray.  Another option is to bypass the NumPyArray and go directly to a Pandas dataframe using a function like this (slightly modified from this [github](https://gist.github.com/d-wasserman/e9c98be1d0caebc2935afecf0ba239a0)):

```py
"""
Function will convert an arcgis table or feature class into a pandas dataframe
with an object ID index, and the selected input fields using an arcpy.da.SearchCursor.
    :param - in_fc - input feature class or table to convert
    :param - input_fields - fields to input to a da search cursor for retrieval
    :param - query - sql query to grab appropriate values
    :returns - pandas.DataFrame
"""
def arc_to_df(in_fc, input_fields=None, query=""):
    OIDFieldName = arcpy.Describe(in_fc).OIDFieldName
    if input_fields:
        final_fields = [OIDFieldName] + input_fields
    else:
        final_fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(in_fc) if f.type not in ['Geometry','Blob']]
        
    data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_fc,final_fields,where_clause=query)]
    fc_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=final_fields)
    fc_dataframe = fc_dataframe.set_index(OIDFieldName,drop=True)
    return fc_dataframe
```

Comment: Success! I had those starred too and neither worked - great modification!